# How to redirect to another url after sending a POST request to admin:auth_user_password_change in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm using the built in django admin site for the application's admin site in a sense that `POST` requests are built identically to its equivalent admin site, and sent to the same `url`s. So it's like the application admin site is just a wrapper for the admin site.

My problem is, I don't know how to redirect back to `url` where it was originally posted. Currently it redirects to the Change User admin page. I'd like it to redirect back to the page.

Here's my `change-password-template.html`:

```
<div>
    <form action="{% url 'admin:auth_user_password_change' user.pk %}" method="post" id="change-password-form">
    {% csrf_token %}
    # ... here goes the password fields
    <input type="submit" value="Change password">
        </div>
            <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{% url 'change_password' id=user.pk%}"> # my attempt at trying to redirect back to the original webpage
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

So, it *does* correctly post to `admin/auth/user/{{user.pk}}/password/` but instead of redirecting *back* to the that page it instead redirects to: `admin/auth/user/{{user.pk}}/change/`. How can I make it do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The wrong way to do it...

You would need to overwrite the `user_change_password` method in your User admin, since that is where the redirect happens:

```
# contrib.auth.admin.py

    def user_change_password(self, request, id, form_url=''):
        ...
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = self.change_password_form(user, request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                ...
                return HttpResponseRedirect(
                    reverse(
                        '%s:%s_%s_change' % (
                            self.admin_site.name,
                            user._meta.app_label,
                            user._meta.model_name,
                        ),
                        args=(user.pk,),
                    )
                )
```

Since this `ModelAdmin` is registered in the `auth` app, you will need to unregister that, add your own custom `UserAdmin`. There are clear instructions on how to do this in the [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model). Once you have done that simply overwrite the method above and edit the redirect.

This would be much more effort than it's worth however, and more importantly it would also be a nasty hack. It's not what the admin interface is intended for. (It would also have the unintended side-effect that when you actually do use the admin app, it will now redirect to wherever you now have told it to - this would be very unusual behaviour).

#### A better solution...

If you want to add an end-point where a user can change their password it's not difficult to do it yourself, and that would be the best solution in this case.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse

def change_password(request, user_id):
    new_password = request.POST["password"]
    user = User.objects.get(id=user_id)
    user.set_password(new_password)
    user.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('your_url_here))
```

You'll need to add some additional checks (e.g. make sure the user has the appropriate permissions, make sure the request is a POST etc.).

#### Probably better still...

Django actually has a built in view for doing this, that you can subclass to customise.

```
# views.py
from django.contrib.auth.views import PasswordChangeView

class MyPasswordChangeView(PasswordChangeView):
    success_url = reverse("url_to_redirect_to")

# urls.py
urlpatters = [
    path('change_password', MyPasswordChangeViews.as_view())
]
```

You can read more about these built in views [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/#module-django.contrib.auth.views).

Comment: Ahhh. I tried to go "All HTML" route here as I saw an example wherein a user can change his own password in a similar structure as I said, and posted it to `{% url 'password_change' %}` but the equivalent function in v`iew` only contains `return redirect('/profile/?status=error')` so I figured he must have used something pre-built to pull it off?

Comment: @mashedpotatoes ah, there is actually a built in view that you can use. I had forgotten about that. I've added another way of doing what you want which uses django's built in `PasswordChangeView`. If you're happy with this solution please mark the answer as correct :)

Comment: I'm doing this as an admin changing the user's password, not the user himself. My understanding of `PasswordChangeView` is it's for the user changing his own password. Is there a way to use this view as an admin?

Comment: If you want to restrict a view to just admin users, you can use the `user_passes_test` decorator. Or for class based views such as this one, you can use the `UserPassesTestMixin`. You can read about it here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.mixins.UserPassesTestMixin

Comment: But then how to indicate the `id` of the `User` whose password is going to be changed in `PasswordChangeView`? I expect something like in your 2nd solution where you need the `user_id` to do so..